# Children are lost in particles to mesh conversion

Tags: particles

When I render the scene they are gone,too, and I just have the number of hairs given in the Emmision section.  Is it supposed be this way? I use dupli objects as particles.

Comment: When a dupli object is used, there is a "convert" button available in the particle modifiers panel.

Comment: That will lead to create many independent object but still duplis. You should select them and make them single user (menu object/relations/make single user). Some more details here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145709/how-to-make-this-thorny-decimated-effect/145733#145733