# How to make this thorny decimated effect?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I would like to use a modifier or something to quickly get something like the picture below without too much hand modeling.

Is this noise effect possible to apply such a remesh to a base mesh?

[image]

Comment: particles or tissue addon?

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the leads, I must add that I need proper lowpoly topography as well

Comment: actually your body can be low-poly, and your particle or tissue objects as well. Maybe particles are more appropriate

Comment: @moonboots may I ask what particle add-on you mean?

Comment: no I meant Particles > Hairs, but you need to try...

Comment: Depending on your source material you could try using Remesh to get consistent vertex density and possibly help with topology, then Triangulate and finally use Displace with distorted noise texture to achieve more contrast in normals.

Comment: ^ Oh and of course Decimate after Remesh*

Answer (score 3):

Using a child object for hair particle system can give something close to what we want.

[image]

To do it, I started from a free model downloaded, then:

- Added a particle system (the parameters are visible in the image) with an object as render element (a small pyramid)
- Convert the particles to mesh using the convert button in the modifiers panel
- Here you get individual instances of the initial pyramid. You need to select them all and use the menu "object/relation/make single user" to make independent instances of this pyramid
- Once done, select and merge them all using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- I've also added a material, and a rapidly done texture on it.

Variations can be obtained with different ways:

- The amount of particles
- Scale and scale randomness in the particle system setting
- Scale of the particle object and its shape, of course
- Add a second particle system with another shape as render object
- ...

Once the final mesh obtained, you can:

- Resize individual pyramids inside the mesh (scale using 'individual origin' as pivot point)
- Give a try at "merge by distance" (with a relatively big distance), which allow to link several pyramid parts

I also think that the material and textures on it are important for the final effect. Here the texture is roughly done but you may pay attention to this point if you want to go further.

The blend file below contains several attempts, so you can play with it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, I will eventually need to remesh it because it will be printed, but thanks for the file alot.

Comment: @JonneyShih, not sure this kind of model can be manifold. I did not know this was for a print.

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick to do something close to this:

- In *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate.
- In the *Select* menu select *Random*, play with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel.
- Scale with <kbd>S</kbd>.
- You've got a thorny effect.

[image]